# How do you prevent two persons from editing the same file?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010, How do you prevent two persons from editing the same file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to remove the multiple checkout option.

> You will need permissions on the Team Project to change it – if you are unsure, speak to your TFS Administrator.
>
> To get to the option itself, first go into Visual Studio, to the Team Explorer and then right click on the project you want to change the option for. Then select Team Project Settings, then select Source Control.
> In the dialog that appears, untick “Enable multiple check-out” and hit ok.

(quoted from http://www.neillans.co.uk/?p=492)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on a specific file/check-out, when you choose to Check Out a file the dialog allows you to select from a handful of lock types that can prevent other developers from checking out or in that file while you have it checked out.

[image: Checkout Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 follow the steps:
1. Open Team Explorer if VS and go to `Settings`
[image]

2. Open Team Project `Source Control` Settings and uncheck `Enable multiple check-out`

[image]